# How to install jdk 1.5 .bin file?

Tags: java

I have downloaded installation file(jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-amd64.bin) from [here](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/java-archive-javase5-downloads.html).

But this is a .bin file.

So how do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you can just make it executable (`chmod +x jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-amd64.bin`) and run it with `./jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-amd64.bin`
Or you can directly run it with `sh jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-amd64.bin`

The above assumes you run the commands in a terminal (Ctlr + Alt + T)